# How to keep username in header

Tags: android, database

My database have two table, which is login and details.
login is used to store `username (PK)`, and password and details is to store the username (FK), user's photo, details..

I want to keep the username shown in header so I can get the username and store it in `details table.`

How try to use bundles get extras() method to get the username and shown in header, but can't work if I intent back to those page.

Any idea how can I fix the username in header? 
Or what should I do to ensure the user's details can store in the correct user database when user click "store button".

Comment: can't you use a TextView at top of layout and change the name by passing inside intent and get from getExtras()?

Comment: why dont you set it in preferences and retrive it from there ;)

Comment: @Chintan, i try this method but can't work.:(

Comment: @droidhot, what u mean by set "preferences and retrieve it"? can explain for more details? Sorry, i'm newbie><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `Activity1` --- > `Activity2`

You can send the `UserName` by this method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("UserName ", UserName );
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrive the `Extra()` in `Activity2`, you need this code

`String UserName = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserName ");`

Hope this helps

**Below Edit for Better Understanding**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    private String UserName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        UserName= (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserName");
        Log.i(Tag, "UserName: "+ UserName);
     }

    // you can call this method from click or where ever you want
    private void AnyMethod()
    {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity3.class);
           intent.putExtra("UserName ", UserName );
           startActivity(intent);
    }

 }
```

Comment: i also try to use this method, but since i get the username from edittext, it got error.

For eg: user key in username in login page, after intend to 2nd page to show the user profile, user add item in 3rd page. When do adding want to return 2nd it occurs error and the apps forced close.

I notice this happened because the get Extra() from login in pages, but when return to 2nd page(user profile) then no more data can get from the edittext in login, So the app will forced close.

@MDMalik, any idea?

Comment: as i understood from you. get the data from edittext and store it in a variable. now refer this variable every where remember when ever you more ( from one activity to another ) you have to follow the above steps. Its better to declare your UserName as class level because if you are returning from Activity3 ---(back to)---> activity2 then the class variable will have UserName

Comment: "Declare UserName as class level" mean I have to create a new class to store the UserName, after that I just to call this class if I want to display the UserName? Good idea, have to try it. Thanks.^^ @MDMalik

Comment: I meant this   public class Activity2 extends Activity {
 private ProgressBar progress;

Just After the name of the Class declare the variable

Comment: but how can I putExtra in the class of "Store UserName" if I not intend this class?

Cause when I click the button should be intend to Activity2.class.

SO how to modify this:

**Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("UserName ", UserName );
startActivity(intent); **

So I can putExtra in "Store UserName" class.

Any idea? @MDMalik

Comment: declare below the class but intialize it onCreate method @user2301281

Comment: Sorry, don't understand.><
Any example?

Comment: Thanks, I think I can get the idea. Thanks you sooo much, u save my time^^. @MDMalik

Comment: I had try and it's WORK and go smoothly!! You save my life. Thanksssssssssss^^
@MDMalik

Answer (score 0):

You can have static object in the activity that object contains username and details of the user. When you intent back then you can assign current object to that static object. In this way you will be able to get the same user on previous activity.

Let's say you have an activity **A** from which you intent to the details activity. Create a public static user object that contains all the details of that user in **A**. When you intent back from details activity then assign **A.user** = current user object. In this way you can have the same user after you intent back and you can show username on the header on.

Comment: how to have static object? Can you show me an example or reference link? Not really understand how it work. Cause i'm very new in android, sorry.><
@Raheel

Comment: Create a class User which contains getter and setters of username, password and details. Create an object public static User user;
Use this user object to assign values and do the trick I told you above.